# Withdraw money from ATM

Tags: java

I need to print out something like these.

```
If the input is 60, then the output should be "Here is 3 $20 notes and 0 $50 notes."
If the input is 100, then the output should be "Here is 0 $20 notes and 2 $50 notes."
If the input is 120, then the output should be "Here is 1 $20 notes and 2 $50 notes."
```

Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, n = input.nextInt();
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        if (n % 50 == 0) {
            j = n/50;
            for (i = 1; i != j+1; i++) {
                y++;
            }
            System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and " + y + " $50 notes.");
        }   
        else if (n % 20 == 0 && n < 100) {
            j = n/20;
            for (i = 1; i != j+1; i++) {
                x++;
            }
            System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and " + y + " $50 notes.");
        }
        else if ((n % 100 != 0) && (n > 100) && (n % 20 == 0)) {
            y = n/100;
            int l = n-(y*100);
            if (l % 20 == 0) {
                int k = l/20;
                for (i = 1; i != k+1; i++) {
                    x++;
                }
                System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and " + y*2 + " $50 notes.");
            }
        }
        else if ((n % 50 != 0) && (n > 50)) {
            y = n/50;
            int l = n-(y*50);
            if (l % 20 == 0){
                int k = l/20;
                for (i = 1; i != k+1; i++) {
                    x++;
                }
                System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and " + y + " $50 notes.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, the value you input cannot be withdrew.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I did so far. It does not work with input of 110, 130, 210, etc.

Comment: "It does not work". You want us to go and guess what's wrong? My guess, you're making it way too difficult and are loosing yourself in redundant code. have you tried simplifying your code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get what you need, there is no need for such amount of conditions. 
As long as you have a well thought order in your code, and you re-use duplicated code, one single conditional statement will suffice:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATM {

    private static int input = 0;
    private static int nrOf100s = 0;
    private static int nrOf50s = 0;
    private static int nrOf20s = 0;
    private static int nrOf5s = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        nrOf100s = getValue(100); // run these in a different order, and your result will be wrong
        nrOf50s = getValue(50);
        nrOf20s = getValue(20);
        nrOf5s = getValue(5);

        System.out.println("nr of 100s: " + nrOf100s);
        System.out.println("nr of 50s:  " + nrOf50s);
        System.out.println("nr of 20s:  " + nrOf20s );
        System.out.println("nr of 5s:   " + nrOf5s);
        System.out.println("nr of 1s:   " + input); // no special variable needed for value of 1's. the remainder applies here
    }

    private static int getValue(int divisor) {
        if( input < divisor ) {
            return 0; // this happens if you try to get nr of 100s when the input is less than 100 (for instance)
        }
        int result = input / divisor;
        input = input % divisor; // don't forget to reduce the value of input
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a shrewd approach which fits Java very well. Should be accepted. If your output needs to be a single String, you can just concatenate all nrOf* variables.